# What is the plant genus or species which is most durable to darkness?

Tags: botany

I would like to buy indoor plants to put them in a room which usually have a very low amount of natural and/or artificial light.

I understand that such indoor plants are usually low-height (up to 1 meter height) domesticated cultivar subspecies of species native to central or deep parts of rain forests from around the world.

What is the plant genus or species (or other taxon) which is most durable to darkness (so if I leave my apartment almost totally dark up to no more than one week, it will stay strong)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, we could consider several situations:

- Plants with no chlorophyll therefore requiring no light - Indian Pipe is one example but that requires association with tree roots
- Fungi, not really plants but grow quite nicely in the dark
- Do you have a cold room at your disposal? Many plants can have their metabolism slowed to a crawl at close to zero degrees C. Rosemary for example will tolerate quite low temperatures and lack of water for weeks and will continue growing normally when returned to warm conditions, similarly Pelargoniums
- Aspidistra (Cast Iron Plant) is an example of a Victorian favourite. It was convenient since it would survive a long time in gloomy hallways along with Dickensian ghosts
- Tradescantia zebrina, particularly the very white leaved types, survive quite nicely in low light with humidity (bathroom, perhaps) provided you can give them only enough water to stop them dying; another that fits this situation is Fittonia, but this one needs the high humidity and moist roots and does not like being cold.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two individual plants that might put up  with those conditions; *Zamioculus zamiifolia*, commonly known as the ZZ plant (for obvious reasons) and *Aspidistra*, common name cast iron plant. The ZZ plant will tolerate darker situations quite well, but it won't really grow very much with low light. Aspidistra, in dark conditions, will not need much water, because it won't grow much either - they are slow growing anyway. if you buy an Aspidistra, be sure to get a plain green one, not a variegated type - many (though not all) variegated plants need medium to bright light conditions to maintain their variegation. These plants do not belong to the same Family - ZZ plant is Araceae family, Aspidistra is Asparagaceae family. The Araceae family includes plants like Syngonium, Dieffenbachia, Epipremnum and Philodrendron - most (though not all) members of this Family will do reasonably well with low to medium light levels

However, there's a difference between low light and no light - all plants need some daylight, or a grow light, to remain healthy over time. A whole week of total darkness more than once or twice a year isn't really advisable. Further info on Aspidistra https://dengarden.com/gardening/Caring-for-Aspidistra-Cast-Iron-Plant and ZZ plant https://www.joyusgarden.com/3-reasons-zz-plant/

Answer (score 0):

for dark environments and shade tolerant plant genus or species I recommend

Begonia 
[image: this is an unnamed variety any suggestions?]

Calathea 
[image]
photo from https://www.thejoyofplants.co.uk/calathea

Pothos 
[image]
photo from
https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/home/gardening/a21764093/best-houseplant-pothos/

Peperomia
[image]
photo from 
https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/294845106839070630/

there are exceptions in each of these  species but they are a great place to start.

most of the above lants would be perfect for indoor plants and they do look amazing.
there are exceptions in each of those species but mostly they can tolerate darker environments, but just like most plants they do love some sunlight